# How do you add a beta code authentication to a rails site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, submit, helper, beta

I have two different pages, one is to enter the beta code, and the other is to actually sign up. Before gaining access to the signup page one must first enter a correct beta key.

How can I check the input, when the user clicks the submit button, with a list of beta keys and then redirect to the sign up page. What I actually want to do is call a helper when the user clicks submit that is able to take the info from the beta code textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called whitelisting. See [Whitelisting with devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167576/whitelisting-with-devise) for examples.